# Cubic residue modulo prime number

Tags: java, algorithm

I want to solve x in the equation x^3 + 1 = 0 mod p. p is a prime. I implemented my code using the paper at https://eprint.iacr.org/2009/457.pdf

I am getting correct answer for p % 3 == 2, but wrong answer for p % 2 = 1. Can anyone help me?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;

class cube_root {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        long a = sc.nextInt();
        long p = sc.nextInt();
        long x = f(a, p);
        System.out.println(x);
    }

    public static long f(long a, long p) {
        if (p == 2) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (p == 3) {
            return 2;
        }
        long q = GCD(3, p - 1);
        long x = powmod(a, (p - 1) / q, p);
        if (x != 1) {
            return -1;
        }
        long m = p - 1;
        long s = 0;
        for (; m % 3 == 0; m /= 3) {
            s++;
        }
        long t = m;
        long k = m / 3;
        long rem = m % 3;
        long b = 0;
        for (long i = 2; i < p; i++) {
            long g = GCD(3, p - 1);
            long y = powmod(i, (p - 1) / g, p);
            if (y != 1) {
                b = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        long c = powmod(b, t, p);
        long r = powmod(a, t, p);
        long h = 1L;
        long cp = powmod(c, (long)Math.pow(3, (int)s - 1), p);
        c = inv(c, p);
        for (long i = 1; i < s; i++) {
            long d = powmod(r, (long)Math.pow(3, (int)(s - t - 1)), p);
            if (d == cp) {
                h *= c;
                r *= (c * c * c);
            } else if (d != 1 || d == cp * cp) {
                h *= (c * c);
                r *= ((c * c * c) * (c * c * c));
            }
            c = powmod(c, 3, p);
        }
        r = h * powmod(a, k, p);
        if (rem == 1) {
            r = inv(r, p);
        }
        return r;
    }

    public static long GCD(long a, long b) {
        if (b == 0) {
            return a;
        }
        return GCD(b, a % b);
    }

    public static long powmod(long a, long p, long n) {
        long r = a % n;
        if (p == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (p == 1) {
            return r;
        }
        if (p % 2 == 1) {
            r = powmod(a, p / 2, n) % n;
            r = r * r % n;
            return r * a % n;
        } else {
            r = powmod(a, p / 2, n) % n;
            r = r * r % n;
            return r;
        }
    }

    public static long inv(long a, long p) {
        return powmod(a, p - 2, p);
    }
}
```

Comment: This needs the `algorithm` tag, and i am not sure if it fits better here or the math stackexchange.

Comment: I found the algorithm in the paper I mentioned. I tried to implement. I think I made a small mistake somewhere. I am unable to find it. :(

Comment: please please use better name for your function and variable, f a p r x what are this? how could we understand what you do easily?

Comment: The variables are taken exactly from the paper I mentioned (page 4 of the pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Without much studying of the algorithm in that paper, I would suggest you debug your program and look for these errors:

(the code snippets are chosen just to demostrate the error, you will need to examine carefully what the program actually does and what it should do)

**1. overflow error**

e.g.

```
long r = powmod(a, t, p);
...
r *= ((c * c * c) * (c * c * c));
```

`long` may not be big enough for what you are doing here.

Range of long is about 2^64, and cuberoot of that is about 2642245. It is not hard to overflow long in this case.

Consider using [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

**2. of-by-one error**

e.g.

```
for (; m % 3 == 0; m /= 3) {
    s++;
}
```

does `s` get increased as it should be? one more time? one less time?